# Как обойти метод setDisable(true) в JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы после установки текстовому полю метода setDisable в true, работал tooltip и по событию от мыши выполнялись какие-либо действия.

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPromptText("текстовое поле");
textField.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Должно работать после setDisable(true)!"));

textField.setDisable(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет замена `setDisable(true)` на `setEditable(false)` + `setOpacity(0.7)`

Такой подход дает:

- визуальная видимость неработоспособности поля
- не требует обходных    маневров по обработке событий
- нельзя изменить содержимое через UI

Comment: Интересны обходные маневры по обработке событий)